# Escape ampersand symbol within inline code

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, markdown

I am trying to execute python code inline in a markdown cell in a python notebook. I cannot get it to visualise in PyCharm so I open it in Jupyter Notebook.

I tried to use a backslash : \&

And use it combined with and without "&amp" : \&amp or &amp

I know both sides of the logic work so I assume it is only the ampersand which is the issue.

```py
#%%
import pandas as pd

data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])

# to illustrate the syntax is ok within a code cell
len(df[(df.Age != 15) & (df.Age != 14)]) 


#%% md
This code will work :   
The number of people not aged 14 is {{len(df[(df.Age != 14)])}} in total.  

The number of people not aged 15 is {{len(df[(df.Age != 15)])}} in total.

----
The below is not working :  

The number of people not aged 14 or 15 is {{len(df[(df.Age != 15) & (df.Age != 14)]) }} in total.

Or : {{len(df[(df.Age != 15) \& (df.Age != 14)]) }} in total.

Or : {{len(df[(df.Age != 15) \&amp (df.Age != 14)]) }} in total.

Or : {{len(df[(df.Age != 15) &amp (df.Age != 14)]) }} in total.
```

The error message is the same for all four :
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (, line 1)

I of course would expect it to display 1.

Comment: Try this: `len(df[((df.Age != 15) & (df.Age != 14))])`

Comment: Put an extra set of brackets around both conditions? No luck, same error.

Comment: a work around is not to use "&" of course: `len(df[np.logical_and((df.Age != 15), (df.Age != 14))])`